# Why do parentheses here result in an error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was getting an error

```
cv.imwrite(f'spidershow{i+1}.png',canvas[i*height:i*(height+1)-1,0:500])
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.0) /Users/runner/work/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:787: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'imwrite'
```

from the code

```
import cv2 as cv

height = 2048
canvas = np.zeros((height*30,500,3), dtype=np.uint8)
for i in range(30):
    cv.imwrite(f'spidershow{i+1}.png',canvas[i*height:i*(height+1)-1,0:500])
```

when I changed the last line to

```
cv.imwrite(f'spidershow{i+1}.png',canvas[i*height:i*height+height-1,0:500])
```

my code worked correctly.

Why did removing the parentheses fix my code? I'm running the latest version of python.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

## Why the error?

The error `error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty()` indicates that you are trying to call `imwrite()` on an empty image. Indeed, inspection of your slicing reveals the problem.

For example, consider the first iteration of the loop (in which `i` is equal to `0`): `i*height:i*(height+1)-1` gives `0*2048:0*(2048+1)-1` or `0:-1`, an empty slice. This will cause the above error.

## Why the solution?

Unlike the first version, the second version is correct. When `i` is `0`, `i*height:i*height+height-1` is `0*2048:0*2048+2048+1` or `0:2047`, a slice with `2048` elements (which is evidently what you wanted). On the last iteration, when `i` = `29`, `i*height:i*height+height-1` is `29*2048:29*2048+2048-1` or `59392:61439`. Since the array's size in this dimension is `height*30` or `2048*30` or `61440`, `61439` correctly indexes the final element.